# Question about multiple criteria List(T).Where

Tags: c#, list, collections, where-clause

now I can not get the correct information

```
   List<HeaderHelper> h = pr.Actual_View();
   foreach (TemplateHeader t in pr.TemplateView()) 
   {
      var v= h.Where(z => z.Country == t.Pais 
                       && z.dia == t.diaTotal 
                       && z.Segment == t.Segmento).FirstOrDefault();
   }
```

The

```
    pr.Actual_View()
```

is a class method for a list containing the following fields:

- Country (string)
- dia (int)
- Segment (string)

The

```
    pr.TemplateView()
```

is a class method for list containing the same fields and same datatype

the list t may contain more information than the list h, so I need to filter the list h with several criteria, but when I run the code does not correctly filter the list, returning a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `v` is null, that suggests that none of the values in `t` matched your `Where` clause, so `FirstOrDefault` returned the default value of `TemplateHeader`, which is null.

Without more information or sample data we've got absolutely no way of knowing *why* none of the values in `t` matched, but that's what the null value of `v` indicates.

Comment: Tanks, when inspecting variables contain the same values
example:h.Country ="AR", t.Pais ="AR", h.diaTotal=18, t.dia = 18, h.Segment="PETCARE", t.Segmento ="PETCARE"

Comment: @Guillermo: Well without a short but complete example, we can't really tell what's wrong... maybe the strings contain something else odd in them, or maybe you're inspecting the variables at the wrong time, etc. A short but complete program that we can run would really help.

Comment: the list h contains empty spaces in the string variables

Comment: @Guillermo: Well there you go. Either trim the data in the comparison, or clean it up to start with.